# Computation of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} -\epsilon & tf_1 \\ tf_2 & -\epsilon \end{pmatrix}$

Compute the eigenvectors. I can easily find the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = -\epsilon \pm t\sqrt{f_1 f_2}$. Maple tells me that the eigenvectors are

$\begin{pmatrix} f_1 /\sqrt{f_1 f_2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -f_1 /\sqrt{f_1 f_2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which I can see is true. However, I have no idea how to derive them? I've tried writing out $(A-\lambda I)v=0$, but it gets me nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda_1=-\varepsilon+t\sqrt{f_1f_2}$, hence $A-\lambda_1I=\begin{pmatrix}-t\sqrt{f_1f_2}&tf_1\\tf_2&-t\sqrt{f_1f_2}\end{pmatrix}$. Now, let $v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix}$, so$$\left(A-\lambda_1 I\right)v=\begin{pmatrix}-t\sqrt{f_1f_2}v_1+tf_1v_2\\tf_2v_1-t\sqrt{f_1f_2}v_2\end{pmatrix}=\vec{0}$$

Now we can solve the equations and get $\displaystyle v_2=\frac{\sqrt{f_1f_2}}{f_1}v_1$, hence the eigenvector that corresponds to $\lambda_1$ is $\displaystyle V_{\lambda_1}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{\sqrt{f_1f_2}}{f_1}\end{pmatrix}$.

Can you find the second eigenvector?

Comment: Many thanks! I got it :) It was a simple sign error on my behalf. Thanks again.

Comment: @L.Henry, you are welcome :)